# How can a parameter be passed to foreach function in a view (Blade) in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

In the controller I have written:

```
$clients = InsertModel::readRecord();  
return view('client.index')->withClients('$clients');
```

How can I pass `$clients` to Blade?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to pass the value of **$clients** variable, not a string.

Replace

```
->withClients('$clients');
```

with

```
->withClients($clients);
```